# How to limit Mailboxer inbox to conversations between specific users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I am creating a messaging system in which a particular user may be a member of one or more organizations. Therefore, if they are signed in to an organization they should only be able to see conversations with users from the same organization but I can't seem to find a way to figure out how to specify that in the query. For example:

```
    recipients = current_org.users
    @conversations = current_user.mailbox.inbox.conversations.where(participants.include?(recipients))
```

..or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a great way to do this, but this is what I did for future reference. I added a class_eval in an initializer file on Mailboxer's Receipts model, creating a slightly modified version of their .recipients scope. It checks to see if there is more than one in the collection and calls .id on it, which was an issue before. It also gets the base_class of the first of the collection since they will all be the same.

```
Mailboxer::Receipt.class_eval do
  scope :recipients, lambda { |recipient|
    if recipient.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy)
      where(:receiver_id => recipient.collect {|x| x.id },:receiver_type => recipient.first.class.base_class.to_s)
    else
      where(:receiver_id => recipient.id,:receiver_type => recipient.class.base_class.to_s)
    end
    }
end
```